# Резиновая верстка блоками

Tags: css

Есть:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
</div>

.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 15px auto;
}

article {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

Не могу понять, как сделать, чтобы разрешение экрана меньше 960px - колонки становились бы не по три, как сейчас, а по две и резиновыми. И так до определенного разрешения, а потом в одну.

[image]

```
@media screen and (max-width:960px) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@XeL077](/users/26057/xel077) написал почти всё верно (min-width: 300px; перебьёт 50% и не будет работать как надо при размере меньше 600px, поэтому не надо его делать, ну и поэтому на одну колонку само не спрыгнет, нужен ещё один стиль), но на словах это не так понятно, поэтому [вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/c2ffmLaL/):

```
.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 15px auto;
}

article {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    height: 70px;
    width: 33.33%; // 
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
}

@media screen and (max-width:960px) {
    .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 15px auto;
    }
    article {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    article {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

В принципе такая градация это по мотивам [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options), там сетка немного сложнее :)

Answer (score 0):

Сделали article ширину в процентах на 33.3% примерно и min-width: 300px;

Дальше делаем wrapper wrapper на 100% или как там нужно. При смене разрешения он будет меняться, и article сжиматься, пока не станет 300, и один article "спрыгнет" вниз. Думаю, понятно.

В крайнем случае возьмите сетку из bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень просто - каждый артикль оберните в уникальный div:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 960px),
            {

    #уникальный div1 {
position: absolute;
задать отступ для блока допустим слева в процентах;
        }
        #уникальный div2 {
position: absolute;
задать отступ для блока допустим слева в процентах;
        }
            }
```

И так высчитать отступы, чтобы поместилось нужное количество блоков.

Answer (score 0):

Менять стили при помощи JavaScript, к примеру, я видел [где-то](http://webuchitel.ru/JavaScript/js_03.html) такой подход. Вычислив при помощи javascript ширину экрана, можно установить определённый стиль для блоков в [обработчике загрузки страницы](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onload).